# Server migration

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp

I want to change the IP address range of my network. Currently I have it configured with 192.168.18.x for both of my sites.

I want to change my setup so that each site is on a unique subnet:

- Site 1: 10.31.212.x
- Site 2: 10.31.214.x

Can you tell me the steps I need to take to accomplish this? Also, what affect will changing the IP addressing have on my network?

Answer (score 1):

steps:

- Lower DHCP lease duration (1h), so workstation will renew more often (to reduce time gap when you will change dhcp scope)
- Then, during down time window:
- Change server IP on network card. Change primary and secondary dns so they match the new ip, and the new gateway ip
- Change routers/firewall/gateway ip
- ipconfig /registerdns on both DC to update dns
- Check that dns entries for them in your dns is clean
- Update dhcp scope to match new scope, and provide the new server ip as dns servers and the new gateway ip
- Reboot some computer to check that everything is ok

Don't you have more servers ? network printers ? I hope you don't use ip instead of name when connecting network share, proxy ip....